# Text is wider than max width table column

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

I have a table and am using the `<col>` to specify column widths. My problem is that one of the columns that is set at 5% width has a title with 16 characters that is wider than the allotted 5% and makes the column width wider. How can I get the title to wrap at the appropriate width and obey the 5% width? I want the table to be responsive and don't want to set widths in pixels. I tried a hyphen which breaks it and wraps the text under, but the hyphen is not conducive to screen readers.

Comment: try `max-width`, but it depends... best to show a complete but concise code example that can replicate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ‘vw’ element (viewport width), ‘vh’ (viewport height), ‘vmin’ (the smaller of vw or vh), ‘vmax’ (the larger or vw or vh) etc.

1 v = 1% of the containing block

using it looks like this:

```
p {font-size: 2vw;}
```

These values are a sizing unit just like px or em, so it can be used to size other elements as well, such was width, margin or padding.

Just in case it doesnt work use something like...

```
p {font-size: 16px; font-size: 2vw;}
```

Alternatively you can use word-wrap: break-word; which will make it flow onto the next line

Comment: Thanks I am using .fixedWidth{
 word-wrap: break-word; max-width:3vw;
}

Comment: You are using it and it now works how you want it to? If so please the answer as correct